# history.js and header redirection

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, history.js

I'm having problems with history.js, which I don't know how to address.

On the website I'm working on we're using history.js to move between pages - if you click on any link history.js loads URL via AJAX, updates the URL and creates transition effect for content. However, we've got also index page with items; if you click on an item, history.js **is not** used - the content is loaded via ajax and displayed within the popup. There's also a situation where user can open the URL of the item (for example in new tab, or from search), in that case user should be redirected to the index page with hash of item URL, which will tell JS to run event of clicking on a link that has the hash URL. However, history.js kicks in and redirects to the item URL.

To reiterate:

- user comes to /items/ URL
- left clicks on item (/item-[id]/ URL), which opens content in popup fine (AJAX request)
- right clicks on item and opens the link in new tab
- lands on /item-[id]/ (not AJAX request), and is redirected to /items/#/item-[id]/ via header redirect.
- history.js kicks in as soon as it's loaded and redirects user to /item-[id]/

I'm using HTML5 version of history.js (which I think shouldn't behave like this, dunno though) which redirects as soon as history.js is loaded (no other scripts on the page). Is there any other way to address this issue besides changing the redirect to /items/?/item-[id]/, which (I think) should resolve the issue.

---

To illustrate the issue:

a.html

```
<html>
<body>
<script type='text/javascript' src="native.history.js"></script>
<a href="b.html#/b/">b</a>
</body>
</html>
```

b.html

```
<html>
<body>
<script type='text/javascript' src="native.history.js"></script>
<a href="a.html#/a/">a</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Using `native.history.js`, which is pure HTML5 version of history.js without any framework bindings found here: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/blob/master/scripts/bundled-uncompressed/html5/native.history.js

It illustrates the point without any redirects. As soon as you click on any link, you're redirected by history.js to URL after the hash.

Comment: Do you have an example jsBin or fiddle?

Comment: How are you handling the /item-[id]/? Are you just adding a hashtag and also adding a javascript trigger? Are you using some kind of client-side routing library or just custom ajax/routing?

Comment: @Stevo Perisic - as it's dealing with redirects, don't know if I'll be able to provide a fiddle. I'll try to cook something up via iframes.

Comment: @HarryH - I thought that's clear from my description, but let's try again. User hits `/item-[id]/`, is redirected to `/items/#/item-[id]/` via header redirect (this is the URL I'm redirecting to, I'm redirecting it to `/items/#/item-[id]/` and I can change where I redirect quite easily), there's no JS trigger. I'm using vanilla PHP and jquery.

Comment: Update the question with code samples you can use.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to history.js and I'm trying to understand. Is there a redirect loop you're asking how to break? What do you want to have happen? What content do you want served at which URLs? What problem are you trying to solve with history.js at all? (That is to ask, can you just not use it?)

Comment: @PatrickM - there's no redirection loop, there's loading of content that shouldn't be loaded. I want, when I hit `/items/#/item-[id]/` to stay on `/items/#/item-[id]/`, and not be redirected to `/item-[id]/` by history.js. I cannot remove history.js as on the `/items/` page there are links that should use history.js.

Comment: Just a couple of point's the first is how much have you used history.js, as using a hash/anchor in location is a bit dodgy anchors are for client side browser handles you would be better not redirecting to an anchor from server and handling it then when your using AJAX to load the content you can use HTML5's push states, then in your server side you check for a header you can send though ajax if it's there you know it's a AJAX Request and only return the content if it's not have your request page included into the site template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to modify history.js directly and add an option `preventHashRedirect`

```
-
#1820 // if (currentState ) {

+
#1820 // if (!History.options.preventHashRedirect && currentState ) {
```

which solves the issue. (basically hash changes are not considered as popstates and don't trigger state changes).

Probably changing `isTraditionalAnchor` function (which determines what is considered an anchor and what an URL after the #) to treat all hashes that begin with `!` would be a better idea.

```
-
#1052 // var isTraditional = !(/[\/\?\.]/.test(url_or_hash));

+
#1052 // var isTraditional = /^!/.test(url_or_hash) ? true : !/[\/\?\.]/.test(url_or_hash);
```

This way you can actually prevent history.js to affect any redirection beginning with `!`. (for example if you actually have an anchor with name `my.puppy`, doing `<a href='#!my.puppy'>` won't cause redirection via history.js.

The below idea of @Martin Barker is still valid, though adding additional redirects strikes me as a little... crude.

Answer (score 0):

Removed -- As you just can't use History.js how you want to as you will be changing a core function in the system that would cause untold problems.

your better of making your own as your using jQuery it's quite simple

a.html

```
<a href="b.html" class="hashlink">B</a>
```

b.html

```
<a href="a.html" class="hashlink">A</a>
```

This will provide the HTML5 .onhashchange event on the window.

```
// support onhashchange for browsers without support
(function(w, l, u){
    'use strict';
    if(w.onhashchange == u ){
        w.onhashchange = function(curr, old){};
        w.oldHash = l.hash.replace("#", "");;
        w.onhashchangeCheck = function(){
            var hash = l.hash.replace("#", "");
            if(hash != w.oldHash){
                w.onhashchange(hash, w.oldHash);
                w.oldHash = hash;
            }
        }
        setInterval(w.onhashchangeCheck, 100);
    } 
})(window, document.location);
```

this shows how you can use onhashchange and to set up any `<a></a>` tags with class `hashlink` to change the hash instead of redirecting the browser

```
// handle using hash changes
(function($, w, l, d, u){
    'use strict';

    w.onhashchange = function(new, old){
        // this should handle loading your content via ajax
        // on $.ajax().success should handle reading the file into the
        // content area of your sight
        alert("hash has said you want to load '"+new+"'");
    }

    $(d).ready(function(){
        $('a.hashlink').on('click', function(e){
            l.hash = $(this).attr('href');
            e.preventDefualt(); // jQuery stop the a link default behavioured of redirecting
            //return false; // legacy jQuery support if you need it for the above
        });
    });
})(jQuery, window, document.location, document);
```

Please note on the javascript there is a u in the closer function however i don't feed a argument into the function for that variable it this is deliberate to create a ture `undefined` result incase some of your code has `var undefined = 'something it should not'`

Comment: A bit of mix to respond to comments and answer. I've used history.js quite some - I was suprised though that history.js would automatically do the thing mentioned in OP. As I've written in the OP - I would want something different than changing the redirect (from `/items/#/item-[id]/` to `/items/?/item-[id]/`) as I actually use the parts after the hash to search the page for element on which to click and trigger JS event. I'm already using push states. Push states don't have anything to do with OP.

Comment: As well - why should redirecting to url with hash be not recommended. I want to use the hash on the client side ONLY, and for all my intended purposes hitting `/items/#/item-[id]/` should be same as hitting `/items/` as far as server is concerned (where if I'll change it to `/items/?/item-[id]/` then these are two different URLs). Unfortunately your solution doesn't address the issue.

Comment: i though you was starting with it but have you tried using php to echo a javascript redirect so that it's handled wholly by the browser. just another note you `a.html` and `b.html` should not have the HTML tag in again as it's pressent in the page making the ajax request, and if your overrigting the whole dom with the content you will causes javascript errors as once js is loaded into the browser it's not unloaded by removing it from the dom. so this would cause a script error and halt the rest of that script.

Comment: Please forget about PHP redirect and AJAX requests - focus on the example `a.html`. In the example, as soon as you click on link, you go to `a.html#/a/`; as soon as page is loaded history.js kicks in, redirects you to `/a/`. I don't want this behaviour - I want to stay on `a.html#/a/`. I don't want anything to happen, no JS scripts to run. I cannot remove history.js. There're no scripts that cause that behaviour, it's triggered purely by history.js

Comment: Oh well in that case you can't use History.js just reading through the source code the hash is removed in `getLocationHref` which is a core function and used in a lot of places so changing it could have cause huge problems, looking though the code i don't know why anyone would use it it's huge horrible and does a lot stuff unnecessarily what your wanting your better off making your own it's not hard to use `document.location.hash` and it does not require HTML5

Comment: I agree that's unnecessary, as I'm already using a browser that supports push states + furthermore I cannot really modify this behaviour. By any chance do you know if this can't be modified - I'd be fine if for example no redirection occurred for `a.html#!/a/` (google notation, doesn't work, you're still redirected). Basically any notation with `#[whatever]/a/` that doesn't end up with redirection.

Comment: i have updated my answer please note i have not tested this but i believe it's correct there might be a couple of problems but it's full browser support and should be easier for you to implement you will just need to create an ajax call using jquery to handle making the request and drawing where you want it to

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58001/discussion-between-martin-barker-and-eithedog).