# Instagram oauth and history.js javascript error preventing login authentication with IE browser component in desktop application

Tags: instagram

A previously working desktop application (until Friday of last week) was using the methods described here: http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/ to log a user in to Instagram.  The application is a desktop application and it uses the IE browser component  https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJd6a.png embedded in the program to show the user the Instagram login page and grab the auth token from the query string.  But something has changed recently on the Instagram login page.
The easiest way to see what is happening is to watch this screen capture:
https://cloudup.com/cKQFpVcTv8E

Basically, there seems to be an error in History.js when opened in a HTML 4 browser like the IE browser component built into windows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoYyx.png

And if I load the full authorization URL ie: https://instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=%2Foauth%2Fauthorize%2F%3Fclient_id%3Dxxxxxxxxxxx%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.xxxxx.com%26response_type%3Dtoken%26scope%3Dlikes%2Bcomments

... the browser component keeps redirecting and loading adding a "#" to the end of the query string.

I've found a few leads on SO:
[History.js for HTML5 - Hack Needed to Not Break IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549661/history-js-for-html5-hack-needed-to-not-break-ie7)
AND 
[history.js and header redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24757216/history-js-and-header-redirection)

These seem to indicate that History.js needs to be modified to work with older browsers, but of course that would be something Instagram needs to do.

Again, this has been working for well over a year until late last week.